# Unable to load easyPrint into Rstudio

Tags: leaflet, rstudio

I am very new to R and Leaflet so this may be an easy fix.  I am able to create fully functioning maps but people are requesting that they are also able to print the maps without having to use print screen.  It appears that easyPrint would be the best solution but I am unable to get it loaded into Rstudio.

I have tried to load it in multiple ways and encounter different errors along the way

```
install.packages("easyPrint")
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘easyPrint’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)

(For this I saved it in my documents like it appeared to want me to)
install("leaflet-easyPrint-gh-pages")
Error: Could not find package root.

install_git("https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint")
install_git("https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint")
Downloading git repo https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint
Error: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)

devtools::install_github("rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint")
Error: HTTP error 404.
No commit found for the ref master

Rate limit remaining: 59/60
Rate limit reset at: 2019-04-04 19:57:05 UTC
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the package, there is indeed no "master" : branches are called "v2", "gh-pages", ...

You may thus try:
devtools::install_github("rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint", ref="v2")